# Is it possible to override toString method in array

Tags: java, string, date, overriding

I have written a program, that gets an ParseException because i am trying parse to Date an array, using toString() method.

```
public static final List<Person> PEOPLE = new ArrayList<Person>();    
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameFile));
            ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> rowdate = new ArrayList<>();

            while (reader.ready())
            {
                String [] rowdata = reader.readLine().split(" ");
                for(int i=0; i < rowdata.length; i++)
                {
                    if(!rowdata[i].matches(".*[\\d]+.*"))
                    {
                        name.add(rowdata[i]);
                    }
                    else rowdate.add(rowdata[i]);
                }

                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
                Date startDate = df.parse(rowdate.toString());
                String lel = name.toString();
                PEOPLE.add(new Person(lel, startDate));
            }
```

Normally, it parses like that `[10, 01, 1987];`

The question is how to do that (if possible) like `10/01/1987;`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just need to have your date format match the input string `[10, 01, 1987]`. Use `new SimpleDateFormat("[dd, MM, yyyy]")`. Then it will work.

Comment: If you can use Java 8, you will prefer `LocalDate.parse(rowdate.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'['dd, MM, uuuu']'"));`.

Comment: This question (despite the title) is not about array, it is about `ArrayList`. Therefore it not at all a duplicate of that other question.